# How can I remove ID variable from URL with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

I'm sorry for complex question. I've got a website that reading contents from MySQL database to get video information just like YouTube.

I've 7 columns: id, title, desc, url, date, whosadded, views.

What I want to do is to Rewrite the url's from `/video.php?id=X` to `/title-music-video.html`

There's ( http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Using-ForceType-For-Nicer-Page-URLs/1/ ) an article for that but htaccess's `ForceType` doesn't works for me.

I know there's a way adding new column to table for the optimized link but i don't want to specify every seo url when adding new records with a form.

I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Why would ForceType work? Anyway, what do you mean by "change"? Redirect?

Comment: i dont know why its not working it always say 404. and i mean with change is rewriting url

Comment: Do you have your current .htaccess code to post up so we can try and figure out where you went wrong?

Comment: So you want a request to `http://domain.com/artist-song-music-video.html` to be internally rewritten to `http://domain.com/video.php?id=1`? Why? Why not serve page directly from `http://domain.com/artist-song-music-video.html` and have no redirects, internal or external?

Comment: all i want to do is here: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Using-ForceType-For-Nicer-Page-URLs/ but forcetype is not working for me.

Comment: @Artefacto: Because that's not the way his application works.. the data isn't stored as flatfiles, it's in a DB most likely.

Comment: @Mark I got that, but video.php?id=1 has nothing to do with this. He's going to have to lookup the video from artist, song, whatever, then he already has the id of the video, he can serve it from there, no need to redirect.

Comment: @Artefacto: Didn't occur to me that `artist` and `song` could be variables. Regardless, in that case he would still need to translate that to `video.php?artist=XXX&song=YYY`, no? How is he going to pull those variables out of the URL as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the whole article? `ForceType` doesn't magically convert URLs for you... it just forces the file to be served as certain type -- thus your .HTML URL can be interpreted as PHP.

Are your videos stored in the database? And your using the ID to pull them up? In that case, what you can do is add an extra column to the table, typically called "slug" and store in it the value of "artist-song-music-video" -- this column must be unique. If you think you might have two pages with that same name, use both the ID and the slug in the URL (like how this site does it -- `videos/5/artist-song-music-video` for example).

Then, what you actually do is rewrite the url -- `/artist-song-music-video.html` to `/video.php?page=artist-song-music-video` or something like that. Then in your `index.php` you typically have a "router" which takes `$_GET['page']`, looks up that slug in the DB, and displays the correct content.

I don't remember the exact `mod_rewrite` rule for translating URLs like that, but there are dozens of tutorials on the net. Google it.

---

Occured to me that `artist` and `song` might be variables. In that case, replace "slug" with your two presumably existing columns "artist" and "song" and look it up that way. Just hack off that "-music-video.html" part. I really don't know what your plan is, so I can't say more.

Comment: "I know there's a way adding new column to table for the optimized link but i dont want to specify every seo url when adding new records with form" -- but they *do* submit the title? If so, just convert the title into a slug; that's the way you should be doing it anyway. They don't need to type anything. Just convert to lowercase and replace spaces wish dashes.